# Grant all privileges throws Access denied exception when executing it remotely

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I'm writing a JavaFX application that allows users to manage remotely different databases. The sql server is in a raspberry pi within my local network (IP:192.168.1.2) so I have granted mypc@192.168.1.3 all privileges in order to test the results of each action. Now I'm implementing a method that allows the user to create a new database. The database is getting created but then I want to grant privileges on that newly created database to another user lets say pi@192.168.1.2. I'm getting thrown the following exception:
"Access denied for user 'mypc'@'192.168.1.3' to database 'createDBtest'"

I've searched a lot and all posts where concluding that such exceptions are thrown when there is lack of privileges. I've tried to grant all privileges upon creation but I'm getting the same error.
Below is a snippet from the function:
**Because the connection is a different class and the database name is known from a previous function, I'm not posting them but I'm sure that both are 100% correctly implemented and that the problem is not found there.

```
public void grantPrivilegesOnCreatedDatabase(){

    setClientIp(getClientIpTextField().getText());
    setClientUserName(getClientUsernameTextField().getText());
    setClientPassword(getClientPasswordPasswordField().getText());
    setClientPasswordVerification(
                       getClientPasswordPasswordField().getText());

    String sql = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON "+getDatabaseName()+".*TO "+
                 getClientUsername() + "@"+getClientIp()+" IDENTIFIED BY '"+
                 getClientPassword()+"';"

    try{
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        int result = statement.executeUpdate();
        if(result > 0){
           System.out.println("Privileges on "+ getDatabaseName() +
           " granted to " + getClientUsername()+"@"+getClientIp() + 
           " identified by '"+getClientPassword()+"'");
        }
        connection.close();
      }catch(SQLException exception){
         exception.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

This code is run from my pc (192.168.1.3) and it is supposed to grant privileges on the newly created database on a user on my raspberry pi (192.168.1.2). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are using MySQL? If so, does 'mypc'@'192.168.1.3' have `GRANT OPTION` privileges? According this article, GRANT ALL grants every privilege except the GRANT OPTION privilege: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-grant.aspx

Comment: Thank you Kelly. mypc@192.168.1.3 wasn't allowed to grant permissions to another user. I'm not getting thrown that exception now but when I log in to mysql as pi and do show databases I don't see the newly created database. Shouldn't I be supposed to see it after I granted the permission to pi?

Comment: Actually my bad, do not reply. I had to say @localhost since the user is in thesame machine as the server. Thanks for your time and help!